# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un "summary" a una función en visual studio code?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Sé que es posible hacer esto en **visual studio** con el shortcut (///) antes de la función, pero ahora estoy usando 
**visual studio code** como editor de código para programar videojuegos con Unity y no sé si existe algún shortcut al igual que en visual studio.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que necesitas una librería para tener comentarios XML. Puedes tratar de instalar el paquete "C# XML Documentation Comments" del market.

Comment: Hola compañero, al parecer esa era la solución instalar una extensión que me permitira hacer comentarios XML. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si esta es la solucion, recuerda marcarla como aceptada @Joss